# JSON. Поменять значения

Tags: java, android, json

Есть ли способ поменять значения в JSON файле? Не считая способа получить все данные, поменять нужные и записать все снова.

Comment: открыть в текстовом редакторе и поменять?

Comment: Ну мне нужно было, чтобы в приложении по нажатии определенной кнопки менялось значение в json файле. Я не совсем корректно описал проблему :-)

Comment: @Батырлан ну так опишите корректно, вопросы можно [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/683369/edit)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, все-таки получаю все данные. меняю в них нужные путем простого добавления через object.put и записываю данные с отдельном потоке. По-другому, кажется, никак...

Comment: можно конечно через замену подстроки, но это очень скользкий путь и не рекомендуется делать (если только это не одноразовая задача)